# Scatter plot in pandas different from that of Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

Here's the result of scatter plot using Matplotlib
[image]

And now here's the result of calling scatter plot using Pandas
[image]

Is there bug in Pandas scatter function or is it supposed to work like this?

Comment: I had the same results, python `3.4.3`, pandas `0.17.1`, matplotlib `1.5.0`. I used diamonds from `ggplot` package.

Comment: Were you enrolled in CS 109? If yes, how did you overcome the Attribution Error: Unknown property color_cyle in the notebook in Lab 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the grey area you see is the boundary of each point. Use the argument `edgecolors='none'` or `edgecolors='black'` to get the same result as you get with matplotlib (see also http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter)